# Office 365 - Outlook overwriting text in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, outlook, office365

We're having some strange behaviour with Office 365's Outlook.  The issue is that it frequently seems to activate the "Insert" key completely of its own accord, and so when editing you start overwriting text instead and blocks of text cannot be selected and deleted properly.  Simply pressing the "Insert" button resolves the problem, but then it will happen again soon after.

The insert key is definitely not getting pressed by mistake to cause this behaviour.

This is happening in Chrome and other Chromium-based browsers, other browsers are not used.  It does not happen when using the non-browser version of Outlook or Word either.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue comes from Chrome. Try using other browsers such as Internet Explorer, Firefox or Opera. Do you get the same issue?

Microsoft Office Outlook (a standalone application) and Office365 (a web application) are differnt things. You shouldn't compare them in that context.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  I'm fully aware of the differences though, I simply included the comparison so that it was clear that the issue was with 365 and not with the computer.

Comment: It looks like you didn't notice the question in my post. Do you get the same issue in other browsers?

Comment: Hi, it's only a Chrome solution I'm interested in.  It doesn't seem to happen in other browsers, but that's why I've specified it as a Chrome question.

Comment: This is a very frustrating problem. I'd love to have a solution.